# The clickable-row doesn't affect a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

The `.html` file is

```
    <tbody>
        {% for row in results %}
        <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} clickable-row" data-href="{% url "perception:detail"  pk=row.object.pk %}">
            {% for item in row.cols %}
            {{ item }}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if row_actions_template %}
            <td class="row-actions">{% include row_actions_template with object=row.object %}</td>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

The `.js` file is

```
$(function(e){
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

The views.py file is

```
class PerceptionIndexView(StaffRestrictedMixin, FrontendListView):
    page_title = _('Perception')
    model = Perception
    template_name = 'loanwolf/perception/index.html'
    pjax_template_name = 'loanwolf/perception/index.pjax.html'
    # row_actions_template_name = 'loanwolf/perception/list-actions.inc.html'
    url_namespace = 'perception'

def active(self, obj):
    if obj.is_active:
        return icon(obj.get_icon(), css_class='green-text', tooltip=_('Active'))
    else:
        return icon(obj.get_icon(), css_class='red-text', tooltip=_('Inactive'))

def notes_count(self, obj):
    return obj.notes.count()
notes_count_label = _('Notes')

def get_change_url(self, obj):
    return obj.get_absolute_url()

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created', '-modified')
    sortable = ('start_date', 'end_date', 'created', 'state', 'modified')
    list_filter = ('state', 'is_active', customer, error)
    list_display = (
        '__unicode__', 'context_menu', 'state', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'current_balance',
        'operation_error', 'modified', 'created', 'notes_count', 'active'
    )
```

The part of the `models.py` file is

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Perception(xwf_models.WorkflowEnabled, TimeStampedModel):
    loan = models.ForeignKey('loans.Loan')
    state = xwf_models.StateField(PerceptionWorkflow)
    start_date = models.DateField(_('Start date'))
    end_date = models.DateField(_('End date'), blank=True, null=True)

    current_balance = models.DecimalField(_('Current balance'),
                        default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=11)
    operation_error = models.SmallIntegerField(_('Operation error'), default=0)
    notes = GenericRelation(Note)



def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('perception:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def get_icon(self):
    if self.is_active:
        return 'check_circle'
    else:
        return 'remove_circle'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    rs = super(Perception, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    return rs

#Property
def __str__(self):
    return six.text_type(_('Perception #%07d') % self.pk)

@property
def firstname(self):
    first_name = self.loan.request.customer.user.first_name
    return first_name

@property
def lastname(self):
    last_name = self.loan.request.customer.user.last_name
    return last_name

@property
def context_menu(self):
    tpl = 'perception/context-menu.inc.html'
    return mark_safe(render_to_string(tpl, {
        'user': self.loan.request.customer.user,
        'customer': self.loan.request.customer,
    }))
```

The `perception/context-menu.inc.html` file looks like

```
{% load i18n %}
<div class="customer-context-menu closed {% if customer.gender == 0 %}male{% else %}female{% endif %}">
    <b class="unselectable">
        {{ customer.icon }}
        {{ user.get_full_name }}
    </b>
    <ul>
        <li class="tip"></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:profile" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Profile" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:alerts_index" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Alerts" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:messaging" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Messaging" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:requests" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Requests" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:documents" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Documents" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:logs" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Logs" %}</a></li>
        <li class="separator"></li>
        {% if customer.phone_1 %}
        <li class="phone">{{ customer.phone_1 }}</li>
        {% endif %}
        <li><a href="mailto:{{ user.email }}" data-turbolinks="false"><i class="material-icons">email</i> {{ user.email }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:print" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false" target="_blank"><i class="material-icons">printer</i> {% trans "Print" %}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the [row image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYXzq.png), I could click on the button associated to `Randy Senger` which open a little window with different options on the same page similar to [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UTh6.png). Actually, there is a `clickable-row` associated to this row. The problematic is located when I clicked on the button. When I click on the button it opened the little window for approximately two seconds, and it render on another page a little as if I was clicking on the row. I think I could use a `preventDefault` on my `.js` file so that when I click on the button, it is not affected by `clickable-row`. Could anyone have an idea how I could modify my `.js` file to fix this?

**P.S.** Please let me know if the question is unclear.

---

What should be the issue here?

```
$(function(e){
    $(".clickable-row").on('click', function() {
        window.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});

$(".customer-context-menu").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I know nothing of Python. But it seems though, that your problem is about firing events for wrapping elements on your DOM. This is related to **event bubbling**.

Should you bind an event to a parent and a child, clicking on the child will fire both events, unless you specify the context where your event is supposed to execute.

`event.stopPropagation` should stop the event handling from being notified to the parent.

```
$('.child').on('click', function(){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('only the child fires the event');
});
```

In any case, have you tried to retrieve the `event.target` of your jQuery event? It should be different according to where you click inside the parent.

```
<script>
    $('.clickable-row').on('click', function(event){
        // Every event returns an event object when specified as a callback parameter
        console.log(event.target);

        if ($(event.target).is('.my-class')){
            // Do code for specific clicked element
        }
    });
</script>
```

I really hope this helps!